# Ruby on Rails: adding association based on user input, many to many using :through, create and destroy method errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, many-to-many, has-many-through

I'm trying to build a simple project management app where a user can be a member of many projects and a project can be a member of many users. This many to many relation is represented in my models below:

```
#project model
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :users, :through => :memberships
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :memberships
end

#user model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :projects, :through => :memberships
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :memberships
end

#membership model (join table)
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :project
 belongs_to :user
end
```

I'm trying to allow the app user to choose which registered users are members of a project when that project is created, hence using the project's new form i want to have drop down lists to choose member users.
I currently have the following

```
#projects_controller.rb
def create    
    @user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    @project.manager_id = @user.id   

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save && @project.memberships.create(:user => @user)
        format.html { redirect_to projects_path, notice: "Project #{@project.name} was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

def destroy
    @project.destroy 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to projects_url, notice: "Project #{@project.name} was successfully deleted." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end 

private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    end      

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, memberships_attributes: [:user_id])
    end    
end

#index.html.erb for projects
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  <% if @project.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@project.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this project from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @project.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>  

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div> 

  <%= f.fields_for :memberships do |m| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= m.label :user_id %><br>
    <%= m.collection_select :user_id, User.all, :id, :username %>
  </div> 
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>


<% end %>
```

This code adds the association in the memberships table but it takes the current logged in user, i would like it to create an association with each user that the user chooses from the form. also my destroy method returns errors and my forms collection_select doesn't show. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Changes i made:

```
#new.html.erb
<%= fields_for :memberships do |m| %>
  <div class="field">  
    <%= m.label "Add Member" %><br> 
    <%= collection_select :users, :user_id, User.all, :id, :username %>
  </div> 
  <% end %>

#projects_controller.rb
collection_ids = params[:users]
    collection_ids.each do |user_id|
    user = User.find(user_id)
    @project.memberships.create(:user => user)
```

I'm getting the error "Couldn't find all Users with 'id': (user_id, 3) (found 1 results, but was looking for 2)"
it seems that this way of doing it only lets the user add one member how can modify the form to add multiples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i guess you are trying to create multiple memberships for a project, where the current user will decide which users should be member of newly created project?
In that case

```
@project.memberships.create(:user => @user)
```

wont work, as it is generating only a membership for current_user.
So when you pass the collection of user_ids to the project_controller's create method, you should loop through those ids and fetch those users and then
 for each one of them create a new memberships.
Somethings like

```
collection_ids.each do |user_id| # assuming collection_ids is an array
  user = User.find(user_id)
  @project.memberships.create(:user => user)
end
```

Comment: Ah yes thats exactly what i'm trying to do, i want the currently logged in user to decide who the members for the newly created project are. Thank you for your answer but how would i pass those collection_ids from the form, i need to have a way to let the user choose from the pool of registered users. He must also be able to choose as many members as he likes.

Comment: you can use multi-select option instead of collection_select                               <% arr = []%>                                                                                              <% User.all.each {|u| arr << [u.name,u.id.to_s]}%>   
    <%= select_tag("user_ids",
      options_for_select(arr),
      { :multiple => true }
    ) %>

Comment: Glad to be of help! it will be a good idea to instantiate arr as @arr in User model and pass it to the view

Comment: Yes i've done that thank you :) could you help me out with the destroy method as well? i just have it as the default @project.destroy but getting this error "no such column: memberships" it seems that it isn't deleting the join table entries on its own even though i defined dependent: :destroy.

Comment: i think you are missing out                                                                       @project = Project.find(params[:id]) in the destroy method

Answer (score 0):

Seems you missed object parameter in your collection_select , I think it should be:

```
 <%= m.collection_select :users, :user_id, User.all, :id, :username %>
```

And you create membership for current user only when calling `@project.memberships.create(:user => @user)` while chosen user_ids will be in `params[:users]` after you add object parameter to your form.

Comment: I see thank you, now i understand what must be done but have no idea how to implement it, how would my controller receive a list of users from the form and how can i display the collection_select because using my code above collection_select doesn't display anything in my url /projects/new

Comment: Add :users to collection_select and `params[:users]` will contain array of submitted users, so you could create memberships using the code from Atul's answer(`collection_ids = params[:users]`)

Comment: Thank you, could you review my edited question above if that's not much trouble.

Comment: Oh, try `params[:users][:user_id]` or see how select's parameters are returned, sorry for misleading can't check it - I'm writing from a phone

Comment: No worries, it worked out i used multi select as Atul has suggested and it worked out great thank you very much for your time.